# Delete last character in string (Python)

Tags: python, string, loops, ends-with

I have a list filled with string objects. If the string object ends in a `W`, I want to delete/remove the `W` from the string. Also, in the only case that the string equals `UW` I do not want to remove the `W`.

I have tried this:

```
masterAbrevs = []

for subject in masterAbrevs:
    if subject.endswith("W"):
        subject =  subject[:-1]
```

After printing `masterAbrevs` it appears that my code is doing absolutely nothing. kindly help.

Comment: Strings are immutable so you have to change the original array content, not `subject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're never making the change to the element in the list; you're making the change to the variable holding the element *returned from the list*.

Try this instead:

```
masterAbrevs = ['ASW', 'AS', 'UW']

for i, e in enumerate(masterAbrevs):
    if (e[-1] == 'W') and (e != 'UW'):
        masterAbrevs[i] = masterAbrevs[i][:-1]

# results in ['AS', 'AS', 'UW']
```

Comment: you are printing U instead of AS in the first index

Comment: Perfect, thanks for everyones help! Was able to learn from this post!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `enumerate()` here.

```
masterAbrevs = ['aksdjfW', 'adW', 'UW', 'tttttW']

for ind, subject in enumerate(masterAbrevs):
    if subject.endswith("W") and subject[-2] != 'U':
        masterAbrevs[ind] = subject[:-1]

print masterAbrevs
# ['aksdjf', 'ad', 'UW', 'ttttt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought you might appreciate a more pythonic answer:

```
masterAbrevs = ['aksdjfW', 'adW', 'UW', 'tttttW']
masterAbrevs = [abrev[:-1] if (abrev.endswith("W") and abrev != "UW") else abrev for abrev in masterAbrevs]
```

Comment: Though not an issue for small lists, it should be noted that using a list comprehension creates a completely new list.

Comment: I don't think you could call any line over 80 characters 'pythonic' ;)

Comment: If the list is not small, a lazy iterable would seem more appropriate. Plus, extracting the conditional into its own function would make the whole thing more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a different approach using a generator or map expression to encapsulate the operation on the inner string:

```
def rstrip_most_ws(s):
    '''Remove trailing 'W' if s is not 'UW'
    '''
    if s != 'UW' and s[-1] == 'W':
        return s[:-1]
    return s

masterAbrevs = (rstrip_most_ws(s) for s in masterAbrevs)
```

It might seem more efficient to manually change the strings in-place, but Python has optimizations for generator and list expressions, so this approach might not be much slower.